# Apply rotation to camera?

Tags: transforms, camera

So as a follow up to the [gimbal lock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/469/could-someone-re-explain-gimbal-lock-to-me) question, I've learned that for a camera it's best to use `YXZ` euler model (as explained in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno)).

Here's the problem. When I add a camera in blender, it for some reason points downward, so when you change the euler to `YXZ`, rotate the camera `90°` along `X axis`(gimbal), you immediately hit the gimbal lock. That wouldn't be a problem, if you could `apply rotation` to the camera - which seems to not be possible.

[image]

Comment: One convenient thing about the unrotated camera pointing down is that it's super-convenient to make orthographic animations in the XY plane.  (use the Z for layering)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The suggested `YXZ` order from the video does not work in Blender because it uses the `Z` up axis convention, whereas Maya uses `Y` as up axis.

If you want to get a setup like the video, where the gimbal lock occurs when looking up or down, you need to parent the camera to an empty and rotate the empty `90°` on the `X` axis, then set the rotation order on the camera to `YXZ`.

Only changing the rotation order on the camera can't work, the gimbal lock always happens at `90°` on some axis and the camera is at `(0°, 0°, 0°)` when looking down, so this extra parenting is needed.

That being said, I think the standard `XYZ` rotation order in Blender may actually be better for cameras. It will give you gimbal lock when tilting the camera `90°` sideways, which is perhaps even less common than looking down or up.

Comment: Good point about the `Z` axis convention. The set up with the empty works great and you're probably right about the `XYZ` model. Btw, do you have any idea why it's not possible to apply rotation to either the camera or the empty?

Comment: There is nothing to apply the rotation to, cameras or empties do not have a rotation stored somewhere besides the object. For meshes there are the vertex coordinates that can be changed but there is no equivalent here.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are asking this question you may want to consider setting up a camera rig.

There are some example videos online [link](http://www.blender3darchitect.com/2011/04/free-camera-rig-for-architectural-animation/), [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlKKcUk6ydQ), of different camera rigs however I'm not sure which are good to use with the latest blender release. (Nice addon project for beginner/intermediate developer).

Comment: +1. Great idea. The book "Film Directing Shot by Shot" has some nice examples of standard camera rigs. Will be nice if there is an add-on with such rigs.