# What are the benefits of Quaternion rotation over Eulerian rotation?

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, mathematics

What are some practical uses for the Quaternion? Why not just use the Euler X, Y, and Z axis rotation values?

It's not intuitive how one should manipulate Quaternions. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I don't have much experience with it, but it helps avoid [gimbal lock](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/469/could-someone-please-explain-gimbal-lock?rq=1) and is often used for animating rigs.

Comment: There's actually a good video in the Humane Rigging series that was referenced in the IRC channel just now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRD0PgsY3pU .  It talks about gimbal lock and interpolation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quaternion has the advantage that it gives better interpolation between keyframes for arbitrary rotations, compared to `euler` or `axis-angle`, this is often used for character animation and why its default for armatures.

It also avoids the [gimbal lock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/469/could-someone-please-explain-gimbal-lock?rq=1) problem.

You make a good point that the f-curves are hard to control. Typically you wont manipulate each axis them directly, and instead pose the rig in the viewport.

So for walk cycles and arbitrary motion, quaternions are fine, Euler's are better if you want to control each axis and are animating something which inherently has separated axis you would want to apply in order (robotic joints for example - a gun turret where you might want to control 2 axis directly).

---

For more general info on this topic see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919086/why-are-quaternions-used-for-rotations

Comment: Ah hah! So, when you're moving something around multiple axes at once with a single movement! That makes sense -- that's exactly what the video I saw on YouTube was saying, that a quaternion describes rotation on multiple axes at once, so that makes perfect sense in the scenario you described of posing through the viewport. Thanks!

Comment: So, with that scenario in mind, can you think of any time you might want to change the quaternion value in the W data field, other than maybe to reset it to it's default value?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII - I cant think of any reasons to adjust the W, aside from the possibility of the axis switching from `-1` to `+1` between keyframes, but this isn't going to happen unless you already edit it manually or have imported f-curves.

Comment: @ideasman42 Do you know if Quaternion performs better than Euler with Inverse Kinematics, or are they both equal? Just curious.

Comment: IK is applied after rotation is calculated (so no impact on IK output), This isn't spesific to IK, nearly all constraints operate on matrices.

Comment: If any more recent reader is interested in how quaternions work, there is a superb new visualization [here](https://eater.net/quaternions)

Comment: I watched that and now know that quaternion rotations are based on 4 dimensional hyperspheres, and my head hurts. Thanks a LOT.