# Objects snap backs to its original position halfway through animation

Tags: animation, constraints

Link to my blender file.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WApKxEItBW1lrh2O9S3e7V1lGQ0xU3el

The cube snaps back to its original postion halfway through animation. I am using transformation constraint to move the cube up and down according to the rotation of cylinder.

Comment: It's occuring at a rotation of 180 degrees. I would suggest [gimbal lock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/469/could-someone-please-explain-gimbal-lock) may be the culprit.  Could try setting the y nd z of spinning object to zero, by applying or via an empty parent.