# rotation driver - skipping backwards after 90 degrees

Tags: drivers

I know this is a radians/degrees issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it
I have two objects (needles in a gauge) that one should rotate at 10% of the other - it's an altimeter for an airplane model

[video of the rotation problem](https://youtu.be/bMOw_QmnmcU)

My driver :

[image]

What dumb thing am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use a single property driver variable**

[image]

Using the transform channel type of driver variable with Eulers makes it ripe for gimbal lock.

[Could someone please explain gimbal lock?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/469/could-someone-please-explain-gimbal-lock)

If instead single property is used

[image]

The equivalent of

```
driven_needle.rotation_euler.x = driving_needle.rotation_euler.x / 10
```

it will work as expected, so `90` degrees becomes `9`, `180` -> `18'  and so on.

Comment: That got it, thank you!