# Using drivers to rotate an angled lattice

Tags: rigging, drivers, lattice

I am trying to use drivers to rotate this lattice along it's local Y axis. [image]

But when I move the driver object it rotates along the world's y axis instead.
[image]

This is my driver setup.
[image]

Comment: Try changing variable from world (global) space to local space.  Quite often can use a single property driver instead see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164765/rotation-driver-skipping-backwards-after-90-degrees/164784?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#164784