# Armature bone glitches after 180 rotation with copy rotation constraint

Tags: armature, constraints

Setting a copy rotation constraints influence to a number like 0.200 starts snapping the bone weirdly after passing 180 degrees of rotation. How can I fix this so that it keeps adding rotation?

Comment: From the perspective of constraints, there isn't any such thing as rotation outside the -180, 180 range.  200 degrees of rotation is actually -160 degrees of rotation.  You can't do it with constraints.  Drivers may get you what you want (depending on what it is that you want.)

Comment: I see. How can I use these drivers then to copy rotation? For example, even copy rotation from two bones just at the influence of 0.2 to 0.8

Comment: Googling "Blender driver tutorial" would probably be a good start.  There's plenty of information out there on them.

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164765/rotation-driver-skipping-backwards-after-90-degrees

Comment: Thank you very much I've managed to get some excellent results with these copy local rotation drives. All you have to choose is the amount of division on the variables to change its influences like so

https://i.imgur.com/8hPVjAf.mp4

https://i.imgur.com/OqL4cTk.mp4

https://i.imgur.com/T3CJHNI.jpg

https://i.imgur.com/HZUHB1x.jpg

https://i.imgur.com/1xBA4cA.jpg

Yet this begs the question, how would I copy global rotation like this? Or even apply the bones parents rotation to the equation. Like the copy rotation constraint with world space or local with parent

Comment: If you want to do drivers in a different space, you need to use them on something in that space: something unparented, in lieu of world space; the parent, in lieu of local-with-parent.  There is no way to convert local space rotations outside of -180,180 to other space rotations outside of this range (there's a certain ambiguity involved, and that's part of why constraints work the way they do.)  Imaginable problems are probably solvable, probably via duplicated bones and use of other constraints like copy location to emulate parenting, but we'd need details to help you solve those problems.